# How to prove that a projective variety is a finite CW complex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a (singular) projective variety, in other words something given by a collection of polynomial equations in $\mathbb CP^n$ or $\mathbb RP^n$. How can one prove it is a finite $CW$ complex?

Similar question: Suppose that $X$ affine (i.e. given by polynomial equations in $\mathbb C^n$, or $\mathbb R^n$). How can one prove its one point compactification is a finite $CW$ complex?

These questions are sequel to the discussions here:

[For which classes of topological spaces Euler characteristics is defined?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26374/for-which-classes-of-topological-spaces-euler-characteristics-is-defined)

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15087/computing-fundamental-groups-and-singular-cohomology-of-projective-varieties

Comment: Particularly my answer :)

Comment: You may also want to look at the paper by Hironaka: "Triangulations of Algebraic Sets", p. 165--185, in the proceedings from the 1974 AMS Arcata conference in Algebraic Algebraic geometry. The purpose of the article is exactly to give a simple demonstration of a fact which "everyone knows", but which is reputed to be difficult.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Lojasiewicz theorem says that every semi-algebraic subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ can be triangulated. Moreover, there is a similar statement for pairs of the form (a semi-algebraic set, a closed subset). See e.g. Hironaka, Triangulations of algebraic sets, Arcata proceedings 1974 and references therein (including the original paper by Lojasiewicz).

The case of an arbitrary (not necessarily quasi-projective) complex algebraic variety follows from Nagata's theorem (every variety can be completed) and Chow's lemma (every complete variety can be blown up to a projective one).

Comment: Algori, thanks! What about one-point compactification? How do you show that this is a finit CW-complex?

Comment: This is not too difficult - take a completion and then trianguate the resulting couple. If $K$ is a subpolyhedron of a polyhedron $K$, then $K/L$ can also be triangulated.

Comment: That is, if $L$ is a subpolyhedron...

Answer (score 5):

The following thesis seems to be more general and worth referencing at this post:

*[Triangulation of Locally Semi-Algebraic Spaces.](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/63851)* by K.R. Hofmann.

I quote from the abstract:

> "We give necessary and sufficient conditions for a locally
>   semi-algebraic space to be homeomorphic to a simplicial complex. Our
>   proof does not require the space to be embedded anywhere, and it
>   requires neither compactness nor projectivity of the space. A
>   corollary is that every real or complex algebraic variety is
>   triangulable, a result which does not seem to be available in the
>   literature when the variety is neither projective nor real and
>   compact."