# Homotopy types of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables, homotopy-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\mathbb{C}$.

1. When does the topological space $X\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ of $\mathbb{C}$-points have the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex?
2. When does the topological space $X\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ of $\mathbb{C}$-points have the *weak* homotopy type of a finite CW-complex, (i.e. when is it a finite space)?

By "when", I mean what adjectives do I have to add to make this true, e.g. finite type, separated, smooth...

3. I'm also interested in question 1.) for when $X$ is affine.

If you happen to know a reference also, that would be fantastic. Thanks!

P.S. I'm aware of this mathoverflow question:

[How to prove that a projective variety is a finite CW complex?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26927/how-to-prove-that-a-projective-variety-is-a-finite-cw-complex)

However, it addresses only the case of varieties, unless I am missing something..

Comment: I remember I read in the "red book" that the notion of variety and scheme is the same over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Google: no, a schemes can be pretty wild even over $\mathbb{C}$. You need it to be reduced separated and  of finite type to qualify as a variety. David: I expect that separated and of finite type would ensure 1, but I have not really thought about carefully.

Comment: How do you define the topological space associated to a scheme which is not of finite type?

Comment: @SamGunningham Spec? Or, since David's only looking at homotopy types, the Artin-Mazur etale homotopy type (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C3%A9tale+homotopy)?

Comment: What is Spec of a scheme? I assumed the question was referring to the complex topology, not the Zariski. For a finite type scheme, locally it is cut out by an ideal in $\mathbb C^n$, so I know what to do.

Comment: By the way, I expect the etale homotopy type would give a different answer to the analytic homotopy type in general. For example, for $X= \mathbb C^\times$, the analytic homotopy type is that of $S^1 = B\mathbb Z$, but the etale homotopy type (I guess) is $B\widehat{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @SamGunningham I wasn't quite thinking about the difference between the analytic and Zariski topology :-S.

Comment: @David Remark 3 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2784 might be of relevance, it mentions the difference between A^1 homotopy and homotopy of the analytic topological space of schemes over C.

Comment: @SamGunningham I think locally of finite type is enough. For the general case, I don't think this question makes sense since GAGA does not apply.

Comment: The topological space associated to the non-separated ``line with a doubled origin'' is the non-Hausdorff manifold $M=\mathbb C \sqcup_{\mathbb C^\times} \mathbb C$. I think this does not have the weak homotopy type of a finite CW complex. The proof can be adapted from Prop 5.1 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609665. In this case, we have that $H^2(M) = 0$ by Mayer-Vietoris, but the Hausdorffification is contractible.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for pointing this out. I had even glanced at that paper earlier this year but had forgotten. It's reasonable to expect from this that non-seperated schemes over $\mathbb{C}$, even if of finite type, my fail to have the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex. However, the example you give turns out to be a $K(\mathbb{Z},1),$ so the question still remains if 2.) holds...

Comment: The answer and comments to the MO question you pointed to only explain why the complex points of a separated scheme of finite type has a CW-structure, but it does not explain why we get homotopy types of finite CW-complexes. By virtue of a well known theorem of Whitehead, for such schemes, having the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex is thus equivalent to having the weak homotopy type of a finite CW-complex. Such a finiteness property is provided by Morse theory, resolution of singularities, and proper descent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any scheme which is separated of finite type, has at least a triangulation, hence is, in particular, a CW-complex. In fact, by a theorem of [Lojasiewicz](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=ASNSP_1964_3_18_4_449_0), this is true for any semi-algebraic set (one can even get this for subanalytic sets, by a result of Hironaka, in *Triangulation 
of algebraic sets*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. Inst. Algebra Geom. Arcata(1974)); however, the case of (possibly singular) algebraic varieties goes back to the early times of Algebraic Topology: e.g. these papers of [van der Waerden](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0102&DMDID=DMDLOG_0019) and of [Lefschetz and Whitehead](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1933-035-02/S0002-9947-1933-1501698-X/)).

If you only are interested in weak homotopy types, it follows from Lurie's proper base change theorem that considering complex points satisfies proper (hyper)descent (this is Prop. 3.21 in this [paper of A. Blanc](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.7360), which is now published in Compositio Math.). Using Hironaka's resolution of singularities theorem, this implies that, for any scheme of finite type $X$, the space $X(\mathbf{C})$ is a finite homotopy colimit of spaces of the form $Y(\mathbf{C})$ with $Y$ affine and smooth (using Mayer-Vietoris-like homotopy pushouts associated to blow-ups and to coverings by Zariski open subschemes). A smooth affine algebraic variety has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex: this follows from Morse theory, as can be seen from (the proof of) Theorem 7.2, page 39 in Milnor's book *Morse Theory*.

From all this, we get that a sufficient condition for $X(\mathbf{C})$ to have the weak homotopy type of a finite CW-complex is to be of finite type, while a sufficient condition to get the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex is to be separated of finite type. A sufficient condition to get an actual finite triangulated space is to be proper.

If we drop the assumption that the scheme is of finite type, I don't see how we can control/define what happens unless we work with pro-homotopy types of some sort.

Comment: do you really need all of the complicated machinery to see finiteness?

Comment: @user141225 this complicated machinery is called mathematics. And yes, in order to have the level of precision expressed above, you need sophisticated tools.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\mathbf{C}$. I think we should endow $X(\mathbf{C})$ with a topology as follows. If $X = \text{Spec}(A)$ is affine, then we write $A = \text{colim}\ A_i$ with $A_i$ of finite type over $\mathbf{C}$, so $X = \lim X_i$ with $X_i = \text{Spec}(A_i)$. Then $X(\mathbf{C}) = \lim X_i(\mathbf{C})$ and we endow the left hand side with the limit topology where each $X_i(\mathbf{C})$ is endowed with the usual one. This just means that a set is open if it comes from an open in one of the $X_i(\mathbf{C})$. In general we glue these topologies; I think this obviously works but I didn't check the details.

Some weird things can happen here, for example it can happen that $X(\mathbf{C})$ is empty even though $X$ is not empty. Also, you can get $X(\mathbf{C})$ to be homeomorphic to any profinite space you like for affine $X$. If $A = S^{-1}\mathbf{C}[x, y]$ then you get $\mathbf{C}^2$ where you remove (possibly infinitely many) plane curves; so you can get $U = \{(x, y) \in \mathbf{C}^2 \mid x \not \in \mathbf{Z}\}$ for example.

All I am trying to say here is that we should probably require $X$ to be (at least) locally of finite type over $\mathbf{C}$. Not an answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the statement "a set is open if it comes from an open in one of the $X_i(\mathbb{C})$": in the case of $\mathbb{A}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{C}}=\lim_i Spec \mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots, x_i]$, then $\mathbb{A}^1=Spec \mathbb{C}[x_1]$ would be open in $\mathbb{A}^{\infty}$ because open in $X_1$? Shouldn't the phrase read "closed if closed in one $X_i$ instead"?

Comment: @Qfwfq 'comes from' means under pullback by the map $\mathbf A^{\infty} \to \mathbf A^1$.