# Invariance of combinatorial/geometric euler characteristic

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology, euler-characteristics

I am trying to read and understand the paper:

TARGET ENUMERATION VIA EULER CHARACTERISTIC INTEGRALS

by YULIY BARYSHNIKOV AND
ROBERT GHRIST.

And I am having trouble with a statement. First of all, definitions:

[image]

**First remark** The definition of $k$-simplex should be with $t_i \in (0,1]$.

**Second remark**  The above definition differs from the common one.

Now we continue and we introduce my problem:

[image]

**Remark** It is clear it is not an homotopic invariant.

**MY QUESTION(S):**

- Is there another easier (which needs less machinery) way to prove the
  topological invariance of this Euler Characteristic?
- I mean, I have seen that Borel-Moore Homology is defined using sheafs
  or sheaves. I am still a masters student and I have never heard about
  that. Is there a proof of the statement using machinery from a first
  course in Algebraic Topology (Some homotopy theory, a bit of homology
  and cohomology)?
- In the case some heavy machinery is needed could you provide me some
  references to look at?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

- I have tried using Cohomology with compact supports since in Massey's
  book titled Singular Homology Theory he uses it to deal with non
  compact manifolds in  order to prove Poincarè Duality. He refers to

  > H. Cartan, Seminaire Henri Cartan 1948/49: Topologie Algebrique

  which I have partially read. However, since the spaces we are dealing with are not
  locally-compact, I can't use that stuff.
- I have read in the paper:  T. Beke, “Topological invariance of the
  combinatorial euler characteristic of tame spaces,” an idea about
  using one-point compactifications ... but I didn't achieve my goal
  yet.
- I have had a look at Stack Exchange. There is a related [this
  question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1184/is-there-a-topological-description-of-combinatorial-euler-characteristic). However, I haven't found an answer there. I quote the
  part I find most related.

  > The definition of combinatorial Euler characteristic is great for
  >   "finite polyhedral complexes", I think. By a "finite polyhedral
  >   complexes" I mean glue together finitely many polyhedra, but you're
  >   allowed to leave some faces open, so that unlike a CW complex not
  >   every cell must have complex closure. Then you can calculate Euler
  >   characteristic with the usual formula: (number of cells of even
  >   dimension) - (number of cells of odd dimension). I think this is a
  >   topological (but not homotopy!) invariant.

So thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Borel-Moore homology is not that bad, if you already understand singular homology. Instead of the complex of finite chains you take the complex of locally finite chains (this is the second definition on wikipedia). You can prove that the combinatorial Euler characteristic coincides with the one defined using B-M homology exactly in the same way as you do for the ordinary one.

Comment: You can use **any** homology theory, e.g., singular. (Any homology theory gives the same result on finite CW-complexes.) I doubt that it can be avoided altogether, if you want a really rigorous proof. However, this is textbook stuff, not research level. Accidentally, $\chi$ **is** a homotopy invariant.

Comment: @DenisNardin you mean I can prove the homology axioms and then create  a kind of "cellular Borel-Moore homology" so I can prove that the combinatorial Euler characteristic coincides with the one defined using B-M homology?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev we are dealing with spaces which are not CW-complexes since the closure of the cells doesn't need to be in the complex. So "(Any homology theory gives the same result on finite CW-complexes.)" is not useful here. And the statement :
"Accidentally, $\chi$ is a homotopy invariant" is not true since with the definitions obove $\chi((0,1)) \neq \chi([0,1])$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev I am not so sure that the combinatorial Euler characteristic coincides with the topological one. [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1184/is-there-a-topological-description-of-combinatorial-euler-characteristic) seems to indicate that it doesn't. What I meant was simply a sketch of the proof that it is an homeomorphism invariant (since Borel-Moore homology obviously is).

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev ok. Thanks anyway. And do you know any textbook which deals with this stuff?

Comment: @DenisNardin the problem of 


"The Borel-Moore homology is not that bad, if you already understand singular homology. Instead of the complex of finite chains you take the complex of locally finite chains (this is the second definition on wikipedia)." 



is that in Wikipedia is also written that that approach is taken on locally compact spaces, which is not our case.

Comment: @D1811994 I must be confused: the spaces look clearly locally compact to me (they are locally closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$). In any case we should not continue this conversation in the comments. Feel free to swing by in the homotopy-theory chatroom if you need clarifications.

Comment: @DenisNardin Consider the "2-simplex" (as defined in the paper) consisting of the interior of the usual $2$-simplex and one of its vertices. That vertex doesn't have a compact neighborhood in the space.